# Is there any all-in-one library for social networks

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to implement the possibility to post to multiple social networks (Facebook, Twitter...) from my Android application, and instead of going through the APIs one by one I was wondering if there existed free libraries that would allow me to do it with just one link and simple calls.

I have searched old questions, but solutions like SocialLib have completelly dissapeared from the internet, while others went from libs to paid services.

Answer (score 0):

What about the Share api in Android:

```
//create the send intent
Intent shareIntent = Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

//set the type
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

//add a subject
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,  "Insert Subject Here");

//build the body of the message to be shared
String shareMessage = "Insert message body here.";

//add the message
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMessage);

//start the chooser for sharing
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Insert share chooser title here"));
```

You will get this popup:
http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-gn8nnLC70Xc/TrFoY1GxKtI/AAAAAAAAAEI/6UDPHv-Zxv8/s1600/sharelist.png

Comment: It's supposed to run in-app to post updates "via MyGame" with link, icon and stuff, so sadly this is not a valid option.